# How to test that a block was yielded to?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a test which needs to check if a block given to a method is being called.

```
block = lambda { 
    #some stuff 
}
block.should_receive(:call)

get_data_with_timeout(1, &block)

def get_data_with_timeout(timeout)
    begin
        timeout(timeout) {
            data = get_data
            yield data #do stuff
        }
    rescue Timeout::Error
        #timeout!
    end
end
```

Essentially I want to check that if there is no timeout then the block is being called and visa versa. Is this possible in rspec?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common pattern that I use:

```
block_called = false
get_data_with_timeout(1) do
    block_called = true
end
block_called.should be_true
```

Comment: gah! i must have had my C hat on yesterday. Thanks :)