# RSpec thinks that block does not receive "call" message?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to use RSpec to ensure that my enumerable class is compatible with Ruby's visitor pattern:

```ruby
# foo.rb
class Foo
  def initialize(enum)
    @enum = enum
  end
  include Enumerable
  def each(&block)
    @enum.each(&block)
  end
end
```

Here is my rspec file:

```ruby
# spec/foo_spec.rb
require 'rspec' 
require './foo.rb' 

describe Foo do 
  let(:items) { [1, 2, 3] } 
  describe '#each' do 
    it 'calls the given block each time' do 
      block = proc { |x| x }
      block.should_receive(:call).exactly(items.size).times 
      Foo.new(items).each(&block) 
    end 
  end 
end
```

But surprisingly, my examples fail when run (with rspec v2.14.5):

```
# $ bundle exec rspec

Failures:

  1) Foo#each calls the given block each time
     Failure/Error: block.should_receive(:call).exactly(items.size).times
       (#<Proc:0x007fbabbdf3f90@/private/tmp/rspec-mystery/spec/foo_spec.rb:8>).call(any args)
           expected: 3 times with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/foo_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00082 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/foo_spec.rb:11 # Foo#each calls the given block each time
```

Even more surprising, the class itself behaves exactly as I expect when used via ruby/irb:

```
# $ irb -r ./foo.rb

1.9.3-p125 :002 > f = Foo.new [1, 2, 3]
 => #<Foo:0x007ffda4059f70 @enum=[1, 2, 3]> 
1.9.3-p125 :003 > f.each
 => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each> 
1.9.3-p125 :004 > block = proc { |x| puts "OK: #{x}" }
 => #<Proc:0x007ffda483fcd0@(irb):4> 
1.9.3-p125 :005 > f.each &block
OK: 1
OK: 2
OK: 3
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

### Why doesn't RSpec notice that the "block" does in fact receive the "call" message three times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't RSpec notice that the "block" does in fact receive the "call" message three times?

Because, AFAICT, on MRI, it doesn't.

`#each` isn't provided by `Enumerable`, only by the classes that implement it, and in your test, you're using an Array.

Here's the source code (in **C**) from [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each):

```
VALUE rb_ary_each(VALUE array)
{
    long i;
    volatile VALUE ary = array;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0, rb_ary_length);
    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_yield(RARRAY_PTR(ary)[i]);
    }
    return ary;
}
```

From this, it looks like Array#each `yields` to the block rather than `call`ing it explicitly.

**UPDATE**:

Your code & test fails on Rubinius & JRuby as well, so it looks like their standard libraries don't use `call` here either. As @mechanicalfish points out, you really only need to test that the iterator goes over the collection the correct number of times.

Comment: So do you know if there is any way in RSpec to set expectations on a block that it will be `yield`ed to in the same way that you can set expectations on a `Proc` that it that it will be `call`ed (i.e. will `receive(:call)`?

Comment: Good question. I have no idea. Replacing :call with :yield in the test didn't make it pass, so maybe there's a different mechanism for testing stuff that goes down to the C level?

Comment: Hmm, so I wonder if it is possible to determine whether or not a proc has been invoked?  Ideally, regardless of whether the invocation was via "yield" or the "call" method.

Comment: @maerics: this seems like one way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2288239/10569

Answer (score 2):

Blocks are not turned into Procs before being yielded to in MRI, per Matz's comment at https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/71221, so it's understandable that they don't receive a `:call` as part of the yield process. Further, I don't believe there is any way to set expectations on a block, per se, as there is no way to reference a block as an object in the Ruby language.

You can, however, set expectations on `Proc`s that they will receive the `:call` message and things will behave as you would expect.